# Subtract two Columns from a Specific Row

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table similar to the one below:

```
ID    Vote_Up    Vote_Down   Vote_Total
1         3            1             2
2         1            3            -2
3         23           7             16
4         5            1             4
5         7            5             2
6         2            2             0
7         9            1             8
```

How do i Come up with the Vote_Total?

Comment: `Vote_Total` = `Vote_Up - Vote_Down` for every row

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
update mytable set vote_total = vote_up - vote_down
```

Comment: This definitely isn't a scalable result, though.  To scale, you'd need to update the total on the action of a change in vote.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the column,and want to update @ssamuel's answer will guide you.
If you do not have the Vote_Down column, and wanted to select it as a column in query.
This would be the select query :

```
SELECT ID  ,  Vote_Up ,  Vote_Down , ( Vote_Up - Vote_Down)
as Vote_Total from myVotesTable
```

Assumed : Vote_Up and Vote_Down are integer or varchar fields with numeric values.